# Iterate an .xml file and save the text as list or dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, loops, dictionary

I got thus far:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(file)
for elem in tree.iter():
    print elem.text
    list=[]
    list.append(elem.text)
```

and get these as the print result of elem.text:

> . . . VA-2017-VBA-0018 VA-2017-VBA-0020 VA-2017-VBA-0025
>   VA-2017-VHA-0003 VA-2017-VHA-0013 VA-2017-VHA-0021 VA-2017-VHA-0023
>   VA-2017-VHA-0024 VA-2017-VHA-0026 VETS-2017-0001 WHD-2017-0002

But when I

> print list,

I get only `['WHD-2017-0002']`

When what I want is either

> [..., VA-2017-VHA-0026, VETS-2017-0001, WHD-2017-0002]

or

> {1: ABMC-2017-0002, ..., 997: VA-2017-VHA-0026, 998: VETS-2017-0001,
>   999: WHD-2017-0002}

Can someone tell me how to make the list or a numerically labeled dictionary out of texts?

Comment: I think you need to use tree.getroot() to get the root element then iterate over that: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-parsing-xml

Comment: 1. Move `list = []` outside of the loop. 2. Rename `list` to something other than a build in class.

Comment: ohhh getting the list=[] out of the loop did the job. Silly me. Thank you!!!